# Java - Updating JList after changing an object

Tags: java, swing, object, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a JList which uses a DefaultListModel.

I then add values to the model which then appear in the JList. I have created a MouseListener which (when double clicked) allows the user to edit the current user number of that person they have selected.

I have checked that the actual object of that record is being changed, and it is. The only issue I'm having is getting the actual Jlist to update to show the new values of that object.

Snippets of the current code I have are:

**Creating the JList and DefaultTableModel:**

```
m = new DefaultListModel();
m.addListDataListener(this);
jl = new JList(m);
jl.addMouseListener(this);
```

**Updating the object:**

```
String sEditedNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Edit number for " + name, number);
if (sEditedNumber != null) {
    directory.update (name, sEditedNumber);
}
```

**And (when jl is the JList and m is the DefaultTableModel):**

```
public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent arg0) {
        jl.setModel(m);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a `MouseListener` instead of a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`fireContentsChanged()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html#fireContentsChanged%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) on the ListModel.

Comment: Can I do this on DefaultListModel?

Comment: @M92: Why not since DefaultListModel extends from AbstractListModel?

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this however, could I get some guidance? I can't seem to get it working. Where do I add it, and how do I use it to update the JList? I'm trying to use the link provided but not getting far.

Comment: I'm wary of firing an event outside the model, when `DefaultListModel` already does so.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of `setModel()`, update your existing model using one of the `DefaultListModel` methods such as [`setElementAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#setElementAt%28E,%20int%29), which will `fireContentsChanged()` for you.

Comment: See also [*How to Use Lists*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `DefaultListModel.fireContentsChanged()`. But since this method is protected (I really wonder why), you can't do that directly. Instead, make a small subclass:

```
class MinoListModel<T> extends DefaultListModel<T>
{
    public void update(int index)
    {
        fireContentsChanged(this, index, index);
    }
}
```

Use it as your list model:

```
m = new MinoListModel<>();
jl = new JList(m);
```

After updating a user number, update the corresponding entry: `m.update(theIndex);`

Alternatively, if you don't want a subclass, you can just replace the JList element after the user number changed: `m.setElementAt(theSameElement, theIndex);`. Though this is somewhat cumbersome and having a subclass seems the cleaner approach.

Comment: It's `protected` precisely to make you do this. List event firing should be encapsulated within the `ListModel` itself, not strewn all around your application.