# How do I update the quantity of an item without spawning a new object inside my JList

Tags: java, swing, java-11, jlist

I want the quanitity shown in (*) to update the value whenver I select an item from the JList and change the quantity of the item without spawning another object in the list.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewFEe.png]

```
public void saveList() {
    
    if(fieldValidate()) {
        String name = nameText.getText();
        Integer quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityText.getText());
        boolean bool = nextDayDelivery.isSelected();
        String type = itemTypeBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
        UUID productID = UUID.fromString(productIDText.getText());
        Product newItemInput = new Product(productID, name, type, quantity, bool);

        data.addElement(newItemInput);
        newItem();
        
    }
    
}
```

I've been trying for days and I have hit a brick wall now.

Comment: Store the `Product` in the `ListModel`. Whenever a `Product` is selected in the JList you populate the data from your `Product` to your "Product Details" form. When you click on "Save" you get the values from the form and update the current `Product`.

Comment: I have already did this thats how I can save objects to the list.

Im talking about modifying the quantity of a item in the list without saving another duplicate item on the list.

Comment: I'm not understanding your problem. If you already add the Product to the ListModel, then you just invoke the getSelectedValue() method of the JList to access the Product. Then you invoke the seQuanttity(...) method of the Product to update the value and then invoke repaint() on the JList.

Answer (score -1):

**Updated to fix bad link**

A search of the web for "update jlist item edited value" yields [Java - Updating JList after changing an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9865119/1271785)

Comment: Thats not what Im asking for.

Comment: I think it directly applies to your situation. In your description, the user selects Dog(2), and your code fills the form with the values of Dog(2) (meaning you have access to Dog(2) all the time in your code that fills and processes changes to the form data). Say the user changes Quantity to 3 and presses Save. Your code should call a method like```saveEdit(Dog theSelectedDog)``` into which you pass the dog item selected from the list view. (You have access to that!) ...(continued in next comment)...

Comment: ... Whereupon, you write the new values into ```theSelectedDog```, notably ```theSelectedDog.setQuantity(form.getQuantity())``` in this case changes the value which should be shown in the List view. Now, your problem is how do get the List view to updated to Dog(3). Your ```saveList()``` method takes the wrong approach by creating a new Product. Pass in the selected dog object, and update its fields. Then you need to fire an event to get the List view to update.

Comment: for clarity the number inside the parenthesis equates to the quantity inside.
So Dog(1) means quanity of 1 dog.

So when select dog(1) and change the quanity to 2, 3 or whatever it will be dog(new quanity) instead of printing a new dog(new quanity) in the list.  This is because the dog will have a unique id number so you wouldnt have 2 different unique IDs for the same item.

Comment: Nothing in my comments would have resulted in the situation where you would have two dogs of different IDs for the same dog. I don't know how to make it any clearer than it is above. To recap: I described how you would *update* (update != create) the *existing* dog in the list, and *not* add a new one. So, if you were editing "Dog(2)", and changed the quantity to 3, it would change the display second item of the list you showed originally to "Dog(3)". There would be *no new dog*.